# How to turn on the VGA display without using the function keys

Tags: display, configuration

It is a well documented issue about some of the function keys not working on laptops. I am having the same issue with my Display Function key i.e. the key that is used to switch to turn on the VGA output.

My question is, if we cannot get the function key to work, what is a way to do the task manually ?

For some background to this question, please see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/613484/adding-a-crt-display-to-my-hp-mini-laptop?noredirect=1#comment760185_613484).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command line tool xrandr to do that.

Query you monitors with `xrandr -q`, which should give you an output like:

```
> xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 600, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
   1024x600       60.0*+   65.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x1024      75.0 +   60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

The two lines

```
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+1024 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

are the connected monitors, where `LVDS1` is the internal laptop screen, and `VGA1` the one connected with the VGA-cable. You can also see that the laptop screen currently uses a resolution of `1024x600`. The VGA screen is not used yet.

Below that are the possible configuration for the monitor. The one marked with an asterisk '*', is the active one.

```
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
   1024x600       60.0*+   65.0
```

You can turn both on with (mirrored setup/ both display the same)

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output VGA1 --auto
```

If you want an extended desktop use something like

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output VGA1 --above LVDS1
```

Now the VGA screen is 'above' the laptop screen. If you want to extend your desktop into another direction use one of

- `--left-of`
- `--right-of`
- `--above`
- `--below`

Now the query output looks like:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1624, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+1024 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
   1024x600       60.0*+   65.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      75.0*+   60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

The part after the resolution `1024x600+0+1024` of the `VGA1` is the position the screens have in relation to each other. It means `VGA1` has the resolution 1024x600, is 0 pixel right of `VGA1`, and 1024 pixel under it.

To turn one screen of use the `--off` switch:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```